# Best practice for calling JavaScript on a specific page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I would like to initialize a jQuery carousel plugin on the product details page, the  [slide carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

I've found two ways to do it, but am wondering if there is a better way.

First off, I added the script to the plugin to my theme's *require-config.js* file with:

// app/design/frontend///require-config.js
var config = {

```
// When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
deps: [
    "js/main" // path to main.js script
],
paths: {
    'slick': 'js/vendor/jquery/slick.min' // path to script in my theme
},
shim: {
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.slick'
    }
}
```

};

Then I found that I could initialise the carousel in my main.js with:

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "slick"
    ],
    function($) {
        "use strict";

        $('.products-related .product-items').slick();

        return;
    }
);
```

But this approach means the slick.min.js file is loaded on every page, and `$('.products-related .product-items').slick();` is executed on every page.

I could initialize the script only on the product details page by adding the following `<script>` tag to *app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml*

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "slick"
    ], function ($) {
        $('.products-related .product-items').slick();
    });
</script>
```

But this means I need to override a template file and use an inline script, is there a better way?  Where I would load an external script just on the product details page?

It probably has little performance impact if I just add it to main.js which is easier but I'm just curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use data-mage-init for call Widget Js in template

First extend layout catalog_product_view to your theme layout dir (Don't edit core files)

Add attribute `data-mage-init` to div wrap you want to slide

```
<ol class="products list slider items product-items" data-mage-init='{"SlickSlide": {}}'> 
  // Slide content here
</ol>
```

Here is requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
          'SlickSlide' :  'js/init',
          'slick' :  'js/slick.min',

       }
   },
};
```

File init.js just simple widget standard of magento to init your lib

```
define([
'jquery',
'slick',
], function (jQuery, slick) {
'use strict';

jQuery.widget('mage.Slick', {
    options: {
        "test": 111// HERE YOU CAN PASS ANY PARAMETERS
    },

    /**
     * Initialize widget
     */
    _create: function () {
        var self = this,
            slick;

        console.log('test');
        jQuery(".product-items").slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });

    },

});

return jQuery.mage.Slick;

});
```

Comment: thanks this was helpful, but I found that with `jQuery(".product-items")` it's kind of defeating the point of using `data-mage-init`.  I described another approach in an answer I gave.

Comment: also, do you know how do you use the `options ` in `jQuery(".product-items").slick({...`?  Can these be overiden with `data-mage-init='{"SlickSlide": {}}'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with layout XML.

In app/design/frontend/Path_To_Active_Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Packagename_Modulename:path_to_js.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then just remove it from your requirejs-config.js file.

Inside of app/design/frontend..../Packagename_modulename/web throw your js file in there

Answer (score 0):

While @mrtuvn answer worked well and put me on the correct path I found an alternative solution which suited my scenario better was as follows. (I took most of it from the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_practice.html).)

So first in my theme's `require-config.js` I have:

```
// app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/require-config.js
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'productSlickCarousel' :  'js/product-slick-init',
            'slickCarousel': 'js/vendor/jquery/slick.min'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        slickCarousel: ['jquery']
    }
};
```

Then I put the jQuery Slick plugin in:
`app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/js/vendor/jquery/slick.min`

Then I added the script to initialise the plugin:

```
// app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/js/product-slick-init.js
define([
    'jquery',
    'slickCarousel'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config, element) {
        var slickConfig = {
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            prevArrow: "<i class='previous'></i>",
            nextArrow: "<i class='next'></i>"
        };
        $(element).slick(slickConfig);
    };
});
```

Finally in the `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml` template file I called the initializing script with `data-mage-init`:

```
<ol class="products list items product-items" data-mage-init='{"productSlickCarousel": {}}'>
```

This approach also has the advantage of allowing you to use `$(element)` so that any the script is only initialized on the element which it `data-mage-init` is used.